# jenkins - can an external program ("shell script") change stages?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have an external program that does all my build/run/test.  I don't particularly want to try to break it into three different programs/scripts/pipeline stages, but I'd love to get the failure/time breakdown based on stage.

Is there any way to have a shell script change the stage it is in?  I can envision, for example, that Jenkins is clever enough to recognize output such as "STAGE: " from the shell script it is running and switch stages, but I can't find documentation of any such feature.

Splitting the script into parts isn't very feasible - it would require saving a bunch of state into some intermediary tmpfiles specified by Jenkins, and that seems a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience with Jenkins as well as research into your question I can conclude without any reasonable doubt that what you are specifically asking for is not possible in Jenkins or any plugin I was able to find.

If you have the ability to split your process into multiple scripts, then you would be able to achieve the 'staging structure' you are describing.

Personally, I highly recommend pipelines. I have recently converted all of my multi-jobs into pipeline workflows and the benefits are immense. I have also achieved a very useful 'stage view' with the following plugin:
[Stage View Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Stage+View+Plugin)

Comment: That's really unfortunate, because that means I have to arbitrarily chop up a tool flow that already exists, and force it to save state and then restart, just so we can see stages in Jenkins.  So it goes.

Comment: It just occurred to me that I could conceivably write a groovy script that runs a script while reading the output and switches stages accordingly inside groovy.  What a mess that would be.

Comment: It would be a little messy but that might be the best way for you to accomplish what you want without having to gut your existing tool. Sounds like the path of least resistance